# How to prevent "out of memory" exception when creating millions of tables in a pl/SQL loop?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql, postgresql-10

I have a rather complex task to solve in PostgreSQL. The essence is that I need to perform a pl/pgsql loop over an array of 10 and a nested loop over an array of ~1 million. Depending on the conditions of each data entry I have to create around 5-8 tables. This then leads to an overall number of tables within one transaction of around 50-80 million tables. I need to create the tables to have index on them for other `SELECT` calculations, which wouldn't be performant without it. However, the outcome of all of this is actually to have a single table of id's, which is why all the tables that I `CREATE` in the loops are also `DROP`ped at the end of each iteration.

The problem is that I get an `out of memory` error. I don't know how to rewrite my code to perhaps split it into separate transactions or something like that. I have the Postgres version 10.14 and am not able to upgrade it at the moment.

Does somebody know how to tackle this problem?

Comment: You don't want millions of tables anyway. That's likely to be hugely inefficient any time you need to access the system catalogues. I would strongly advise subscribing to the postgresql mailing lists and describing what the overall problem you are trying to solve is. However - if you are determined to continue down this path you need to at the very least show the error message, the pl/pgsql function (NOT plsql - that isn't a PostgreSQL language) and how much memory has been used when it runs out.

Comment: Solve the problem in a different, simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know how to rewrite my code to perhaps split it into separate transactions

You could use a stored procedure instead of a function. Procedures can use transactions, just use begin and commit in your code. So in your loop, you could do something like:

```
BEGIN
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE (...) ON COMMIT DROP
...do your thing with the temp table...
INSERT the result into a more permanent table
COMMIT
```

Make sure you use temporary tables, that will be faster.

However, if you want to use indexes on your temp tables, then maybe you also want to ANALYZE them beforehand, in this case you can use ANALYZE but not VACUUM ANALYZE because that will commit your transaction and if the table was created with ON COMMIT DROP then it is dropped before being analyzed...

Now, honestly it is quite suspicious to create millions of tables, so if you ask a question explaining exactly what you are trying to do, maybe there will be a much simpler solution.

Comment: If you ask a new question feel free to tag me, just add a comment here.

Comment: Thx for the answer and the offer to help. Much appreciated! I will test this once I open my computer again tomorrow.. Just FYI: I am running spatial analysis using PostGIS and pgRouting. For this, I need to split a road network over Germany into smaller pieces and route from one building to another for each building. And pgRouting requires several data preparation (for instance a routable street network), for which it offers functions that also recreate new tables. By cutting down this analysis to a district level using a loop I am able to perform the routing and efficiently.

Comment: One example of a table that I create is a selection of target buildings for the routing in one district from a set of all buildings in Germany. I then need to have a spatial index on that table to be able to faster check which buildings are in 500 proximity of a current building in a loop. Once I finish the analysis for this district I can DROP this table again.

Comment: Procedures seem to exist from Postgres 11. I have Postgres 10.14...

Comment: Can you show the source code for this tool that creates the tables? You could edit the script, add TEMPORARY and IF NOT EXISTS to the CREATE TABLE statements, and truncate the tables at the end of each iteration instead of dropping them... so each loop iteration doesn't create a new table, just fill it, transfer data to permanent table, and truncate the temp table.